# matplotlib is ignoring locator_params nticks command

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a plot with four ticks on each axes. Here is the code:

```
ax0 = pyplot.gca()
cmap = pyplot.cm.get_cmap('RdYlBu', 9)
vmin=0.75
vmax=5.25
sc = pyplot.scatter(X[idx, 0], X[idx, 1], c=colors[idx], vmin=vmin,
                    vmax=vmax, s=30, cmap=cmap)

pyplot.colorbar(sc, ticks=[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0])
ax0.locator_params(tight=True, nticks=4)
ax0.set_ylim([-1.0, 1.0])
ax0.set_xlim([-1.0, 1.0])
ax0.axis('equal')
pyplot.show()
```

This is the resulting image

[image: scatter plot]

As you can see it ignores both the locator_params and the set_xlim/set_ylim commands. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, 
as stated in the [`locator_params`](http://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.locator_params.html) documentation:

> Remaining keyword arguments are passed to directly to the set_params() method.
>   Typically one might want to reduce the maximum number of ticks and use tight bounds when plotting small subplots, for example:
>       `ax.locator_params(tight=True, nbins=4)`

**The keyword argument is named `nbins` not `nticks`.**

Additionally you probably want to set this to both axes:

```
ax0.locator_params(which="both", tight=True, nbins=4)
```

Note that `nbins` does not set the number of ticks, but the maximum number of bins, so the result may be less than 4 bins.

The other issue is the limits. The limits are ignored because of `ax0.axis('equal')` being set after setting the limits. You probably want to set the aspect, `ax0.set_aspect('equal')`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

X =np.random.randn(30,2)
colors= np.random.rand(30)*5
ax0 = plt.gca()
ax0.set_aspect('equal')
cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('RdYlBu', 9)

sc = plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=colors, vmin=0.75,
                    vmax=5.25, s=30, cmap=cmap)

plt.colorbar(sc, ticks=[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0])
ax0.locator_params(which="both", tight=True, nbins=4)
ax0.set_ylim([-1.0, 1.0])
ax0.set_xlim([-1.0, 1.0])

plt.show()
```

[image]